# "React useContext Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, styled-components

I'm encountering an error in my React application while trying to use styled-components. The error message I'm receiving is:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2250:25)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3958:58
...

I'm not directly using useContext in my code, so I'm a bit puzzled about why this error is occurring. I was in the process of incorporating styled-components into my project when this issue started.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalStyle = styled.body`
  background-color: #22254b;
`;

export const AppContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
`;

export const MovieContainer = styled.div`
  width: 250px;
  margin: 16px;
  background-color: #373b69;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
`;

export const MovieImage = styled.img`
  max-width: 100%;
`;

export const MovieInfo = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const MovieTitle = styled.h4`
  margin: 0;
`;

export const MovieInfoText = styled.span`
  margin-left: 3px;
`;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { MovieContainer, MovieImage, MovieInfo, MovieTitle, MovieInfoText } from "./Movie.style";
const IMG_BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/";


export default function Movie(props) {
  return (
    <MovieContainer>
      <MovieImage src={IMG_BASE_URL + props.poster_path} alt="영화 포스터" />
      <MovieInfo>
        <MovieTitle>{props.title}</MovieTitle>
        <MovieInfoText>{props.vote_average}</MovieInfoText>
      </MovieInfo>
    </MovieContainer>
  );
}
```

```
import Movie from "./components/Movie";
import { movies } from "./movie";
import { GlobalStyle, AppContainer } from "./components/Movie.style";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <div>
    <AppContainer>
        {movies.results.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Movie
              title={item.title}
              poster_path={item.poster_path}
              vote_average={item.vote_average}
            />
          );
        })}
      </AppContainer>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

I just wanted to change the css code using styled-components.

Comment: you are not wrapping your app with provider. maybe this will help https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#my-component-doesnt-see-the-value-from-my-provider